# gmap3_tools limitations

Tags: google-maps

Trying to show locations world wide using [GMap3 Tools](http://drupal.org/project/gmap3_tools) module, however, any location over 4750 miles from **default_center_lat** and **default_center_long** are not rendered. Is there a fix? I have looked through the module code and see nothing.

`$distance_meters = 4750 * 1609.34; //1 mile = 1609.34 meters`

Any help understanding why I can't go over 4750 would be appreciated.